# BeautifulSoup(html) returns text with blanks between letters

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am using Beautiful soup to scrap this page : `url= http://www.ville-brunoy.fr/Brunoy.asp?idpage=3458`. To do so I use :

`html=requests.get(url, headers=headers).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)`.

But, the text I get when running this command is not as expected (i.e. different from what I get when I inspect the url). BeautifulSoup() creates blank between the letters and the output looks like that :

```
s.className='';" onmouseover="MM_showHideLayers('letraitdunion','','show'); MM_swapImage('img_letraitdunion','','images2/fleche_survol.gif',1); this.className='li_social';">
<a href="brunoy.asp?idpage=4290">Le Trait d'Union</a></li>
</ul>
</dd>
</dl>
<a href="imprim_html.asp?idpage=3458&amp;lxml" target="_blank"><img a="" src="images2/impr.jpg">l t = " I m p r i m e r   l a   p a g e "   c l a s s = " i c o n e _ o u t i l "   / &gt; / a &gt; a   h r e f = " s i t e _ a c c e s . a s p ? i d P a g e = 3 4 5 8 &amp;i d = &amp;a p p e l = " &gt; i m g   s r c = " i m a g e s 2 / i m a g e s 2 o e i l . j p g "   a l t = " V e r s i o n   a c c e s s i b l e   a u x   m a l - v o y a n t s "   c l a s s = " o e i l "   / &gt; / a &gt;
```

I have used this function for many different website and never encountered this issue. Do you know where it could come from?

Thanks,

Antoine

Comment: what do you have in your `headers` variable?

Comment: `<img src="images2/impr.jpg" alt="Imprimer la page" class="icone_outil" />` For some reason the 'a' from alt is before the src as a property then the rest is spaced. You may need separate settings for `img` tags with `alt`

Comment: my header is as follows:

`user_agent='Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:61.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/61.0'
headers = { 'User-Agent' : user_agent,
          'Content-Type': 'text/html'}`

Comment: I just scraped it using your code without the headers  and got this for that anchor- `<a href="imprim_html.asp?idpage=3458" target="_blank"><img alt="Imprimer la page" class="icone_outil" src="images2/icones/imprim.jpg"/></a>`.  Python version 3.6, bs4 version 4.6.0.  If you are still using Python version 2.x you should upgrade: https://pythonclock.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem comes from the way you use `BeautifulSoup()`.
Instead of doing this:

```
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
```

you should use:

```
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,"lxml")
```

The difference is that with  `text` you pass the content of the response in `unicode` (i.e., a Unicode string), while with `content` you pass `raw undecoded bytes`.